# How to change setting inside SBT command?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to have a command `publish-snapshot` that would run the `publish` task with modified `version` setting (that setting is to be computed at the time of execution of the command).

I figured out how to get the current value of the `version` inside command, and `Project.runTask("task", "scope", ...)` seems to be a right call for invoking the `publish` task.

The only thing that I'm confused with is how to modify the `State` instance with a new version value. All my attempts seem to do nothing to the original version setting.

My last attempt:

```
val printVers = TaskKey[Unit]("printvers")
val printVersTask = TaskKey[Unit]("printvers") <<= {version map println}

def publishSnapshot = Command.command("publish-snapshot") { state =>
  val newState = SessionSettings.reapply(state.get(sessionSettings).get.appendRaw(version := "???"), state)
  Project.runTask(printVers in Compile, newState, true)

  state
}

lazy val root = Project("main", file("."),
                        settings =
                          Defaults.defaultSettings ++
                          Seq(printVersTask)).settings(commands += publishSnapshot)
```

Is there some way to fix that behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This actually did not work for me. I'm using SBT 0.13.7

Adapting what I had to do to the above example, I had to do something like:

```
def publishSnapshot = Command.command("publish-snapshot") { state =>
  val extracted = Project extract state
  val newState = extracted.append(Seq(version := "newVersion"), state)
  val (s, _) = Project.extract(newState).runTask(publish in Compile, newState)
  s
}
```

Or alternatively do:

```
def publishSnapshot = Command.command("publish-snapshot") { state =>
  val newState =
    Command.process("""set version := "newVersion" """, state)
  val (s, _) = Project.extract(newState).runTask(publish in Compile, newState)
  s
}
```

Comment: I'm running on `0.13.8` and this helped me. Although it seems super weird to have the `newState` twice as input to `runTask`. I wonder if this is intentional behavior. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 21):

With the help from `sbt` mailing list, I was able to create a solution as follows:

```
def publishSnapshot = Command.command("publish-snapshot") { state =>
  val extracted = Project extract state
  import extracted._
  val eVersion = getOpt(version).get // getting current version
  runTask(publish in Compile,
    append(Seq(version := "newVersion"), state),
    true
  )
  state
}
```

Comment: Don't need to use `runTask()`. `append()` is enough.

Answer (score 5):

To update an arbitrary setting from a command, do something like the following:

```
def updateFoo = Command.command("updateFoo") { state =>
 val extracted = Project extract state
 import extracted._
 println("'foo' set to true")
 //append returns state with updated Foo
 append(Seq(foo := true), state)
}
```