# How to publish to multiple repositories in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am in the middle of upgrading Nexus version. As part of the process I've set up a new Nexus instance which will run in parallel with the older Nexus instance.

While migrating to the new instance I want to thoroughly test and vet the new instance before pulling the plug on older instance. This requires me to temporarily modify the `publish` workflow in such a way that sbt publishes the artifacts to both the Nexus instances.

I highly doubt the following code will actually work:

```
    publishTo <<= (version) {
       version: String =>
       if (version.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) Some("snapshots" at "http://maven1.dev.net:8081/nexus/content/" + "repositories/snapshots/")
       else Some("releases" at "http://maven1.dev.net:8081/nexus/content/" + "repositories/releases/")
    },
    credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager", "maven1.dev.net", "release-eng", "release"),

    publishTo <<= (version) {
       version: String =>
       if (version.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) Some("snapshots" at "http://maven2.dev.net:8081/nexus/content/" + "repositories/snapshots/")
       else Some("releases" at "http://maven2.dev.net:8081/nexus/content/" + "repositories/releases/")
    },
    credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager", "maven2.dev.net", "release-eng", "release"),
```

I also tried looking into a plugin called [sbt-multi-publish](https://github.com/davidharcombe/sbt-multi-publish) but I couldn't compile and use it, either.

Comment: you got it right when looking at sbt-multi-publish. Can you update the question to reflect the problems you encountered when trying to use it ? (provide your build.sbt, project/*.sbt, project/*.scala contents so we can help)

Answer (score 4):

With [Commands](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Commands.html) and [How to change a version setting inside a single sbt command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14274715/1305344) I could define a new command - `myPublishTo` - that changes `publishTo` setting before executing the original `publish` task:

```
def myPublishTo = Command.command("myPublishTo") { state =>
  val extracted = Project.extract(state)
  Project.runTask(
    publish in Compile,
    extracted.append(List(publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file", target.value / "xxx"))), state),
    true
  )
  Project.runTask(
    publish in Compile,
    extracted.append(List(publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file", target.value / "yyy"))), state),
    true
  )
  state
}

commands += myPublishTo
```

With this, execute `myPublishTo` as any other command/task.

You could also define a couple of `alias`es - `pxxx`, `pyyy` and `pxy` - in `build.sbt` that would execute a series of commands using `;`.

```
addCommandAlias("pxxx", "; set publishTo := Some(Resolver.file(\"file\", target.value / \"xxx\")) ; publish") ++
addCommandAlias("pyyy", "; set publishTo := Some(Resolver.file(\"file\", target.value / \"yyy\")) ; publish") ++
addCommandAlias("pxy", "; pxxx ; pyyy")
```

In sbt console you can execute them as any other commands/tasks.

```
[sbt-0-13-1]> alias
    pxxx = ; set publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file", target.value / "xxx")) ; publish
    pyyy = ; set publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file", target.value / "yyy")) ; publish
    pxy = ; pxxx ; pyyy
[sbt-0-13-1]> pxy
[info] Defining *:publishTo
[info] The new value will be used by *:otherResolvers, *:publishConfiguration
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
...
[info]  published sbt-0-13-1_2.10 to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/xxx/default/sbt-0-13-1_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 9, 2014 11:20:48 PM
[info] Defining *:publishTo
[info] The new value will be used by *:otherResolvers, *:publishConfiguration
[info] Reapplying settings...
...
[info]  published sbt-0-13-1_2.10 to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/yyy/default/sbt-0-13-1_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 9, 2014 11:20:49 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but the problem persists. I tried to revive sbt-multi-publish, but it's really old (sbt-0.12) and uses some sbt internals that are hard to deal with. So I took another approach and wrote a new plugin: [sbt-publish-more](https://github.com/laughedelic/sbt-publish-more).
It doesn't involve any on-the-fly settings changing or custom commands like the other answer.

After you add the plugin, just set resolvers you want to publish to (taking your code as an example):

```
publishResolvers := {
  val suffix = if (isSnapshot.value) "shapshots" else "releases"
  Seq(
    s"Maven1 ${suffix}" at s"http://maven1.dev.net:8081/nexus/content/repositories/${suffix}/",
    s"Maven2 ${suffix}" at s"http://maven2.dev.net:8081/nexus/content/repositories/${suffix}/"
  )
}
```

And call `publishAll` task, it will publish to **both repositories**. 
You can also publish to different repositories with different configurations. Check [usage docs](https://github.com/laughedelic/sbt-publish-more#usage) for details.