# Update a timestamp SettingKey in an sbt 0.12 task

Tags: scala, sbt

I need a way to update a `SettingKey[String]` in my sbt build each time the `compile` task executes.  A `SettingKey` is necessary so it can be injected into application via [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo).  Creating a command is one way to accomplish this per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262798/how-to-change-setting-inside-sbt-command), but I want it to happen when the `compile` task executes, which can be caused by any number of other tasks.  Any ideas how to accomplish this in sbt 0.12?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `SettingKey[String]` as the `SettingKey`s are only computed once - during the project load, which is specified in the documentation:

> For a setting, the value will be computed once at project load time.
>   For a task, the computation will be re-run each time the task is
>   executed.

How about following `Build.scala`

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import sbtbuildinfo.Plugin._

object HelloBuild extends Build {

  val helloSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++
    buildInfoSettings ++ Seq (
    sourceGenerators in Compile <+= buildInfo,
    buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](
      name, 
      version, 
      scalaVersion,
      // Here is the interesting part
      BuildInfoKey.action("buildTime") { 
        System.currentTimeMillis 
      }
    ),
    buildInfoPackage := "org.myorg.myapp"
  )

  lazy val project = Project (
    id = "project",
    base = file ("."),
    settings = helloSettings
  )

}
```