# SBT - Run Task to set a SettingKey

Tags: scala, sbt, versioning

So my general problem is that I want to set the version key based on the result of a task. However the version key is set before the task is run. From what I understand I can't change the value of a key once it is set so I can't change this within my task.

What I want to do is run the task as a dependency to the publish task and change the value for version. I feel like there must be a way to do this, but I have no clues at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change setting inside SBT command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262798/how-to-change-setting-inside-sbt-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sbt-release plugin does this by writing an sbt file in the root of the project containing the correct version. Maybe you can use this plugin: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release

If you can not use it you can check out the source code to see the strategy the creator used.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up going this route but left the question open to see if anyone else had a different approach. It seems they reapply all the settings (I assume the way `set key := value` works in SBT console) but it seems kinda hacky. Maybe that's just the best way to work with SBT... who knows.

Comment: @John `set key := value` copies the settings (with the new key value pair) and reloads the project.

Comment: What is the api to do that within `Build.scala` rather than the `.sbt` file format? I like to keep things a little more explicit and a less magical in my build definitions.

Comment: I have no idea, the `set` commands seems to be a built-in command (I am not even sure it is a normal sbt command).

Comment: Did some looking around, seems that `set` is a wrapper to `BuiltinCommands.reapply` (see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.6/api/index.html#sbt.BuiltinCommands$)

Comment: Extracted definition of `set`: https://gist.github.com/JohnMurray/b3e89764a48fef96a356