# Can you modify the name and version of a SBT build from the publish task?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to change the `name` and the `version` setting when running the `publish` command? Here is my workflow.

I have written a custom input task. It is called with a three arguments `name`, `buildNumber` and `exportLocation`. We work with game and `name` is the name of a specific game. `buildNumber` is the changelist id of the game build in [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com). `exportLocation` is a file path that contains a bunch of XML files that the Perforce build has output. My task parses the XML files, creates an in-memory object tree and serializes the tree into `resourceManaged`. In other words it will generate a bunch of resources.

My ultimate goal is to bundle those resources inside a jar-file that uses `name` and `buildNumber` in it's name and publish the artifact to our internal repository.

Comment: Can you give more detail about what effect you're trying to achieve. Perhaps show what you've tried, what it returned and what you expected.

Comment: @DaleWijnand: I have updated my description to make a bit more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** It's not possible to change the value of `Setting`s from `Task`s since settings are immutable.

You cannot re-set settings since they are immutable unless you `reload` a project with the new values set. That's where [commands](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Commands.html) can help as they operate on State in which Settings live.

See [How to change setting inside SBT command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14274715/463761) for an example of this.