# How to define a new setting and set its value for a task?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've a `myTask` task that invokes other tasks as follows:

```
def myTask = Task <<= (Task1, Task2, Task3) map {(_,_,_)=>;}
```

`Task1, Task2, Task3` take a `tcWebApp` config variable that is a directory.

```
 tcWebApp := file("../tomcat")
```

Everything works fine.

What I need now is to create another task `myTask2` that'd be similar to `myTask`, but I'd like to invoke this task with another directory set for the `tcWebApp` setting, i.e. the setting should have another value for the task. Is it possible?

I've tried something like

```
tcWebApp in myTask2 := file("newDir")
```

but it didn't work. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

```
`tcWebApp in myTask2` := ...
```

It doesn't mean "while myTask2 is executing, tcWebApp has the following value," as you want it to. What it does mean is, "if anyone asks myTask2 what value it has for tcWebApp, it will reply as follows." It doesn't have any effect on the global value of `tcWebApp`; and if nobody ever asks `myTask2` what its value for `tcWebApp` is, then setting it in that task has no effect at all. So `Task1` will continue to use the global value of `tcWebApp`.

I found some related questions on Stack Overflow:

- [Using SBT, how do you execute a task with a different Setting[T] value at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904568/using-sbt-how-do-you-execute-a-task-with-a-different-settingt-value-at-runtim)

Here Daniel Sobral writes "From what I understand from your question, you want the setting to be different for a dependency depending on what is depending on it. This doesn't make sense -- a dependency either is satisfied or it isn't, and what depends on it doesn't come into the equation." As I understand it, that is the answer to your question.

In order to work around this, instead of attempting to reuse `Task1` and `Task2` as tasks, reuse the code inside them instead. Have `Task1` and `Task2` invoke ordinary methods that you define, and then have `myTask2` call those same methods, passing them different parameters. In other words don't try to solve your problem with settings; solve it by means of ordinary Scala code.

- [How to change setting inside SBT command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262798/how-to-change-a-version-setting-inside-a-single-sbt-command)

Or, here's another approach you could take. If you make `myTask2` a command rather than a task, you can do what you want. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Commands.html which says "a command can look at or modify other sbt settings".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually it's not what i want. I have some tasks: `Taks1, Task2 etc.` and that tasks takes config variable which is defined in build.sbt, in your example it's `mySetting`. I also have `myTask2` which is invoking `Task1, Task2 etc.` When I invoke `myTask2`  I would like to have other `mySetting` in `Task1, Task2...` Something like: `myTask2(Task1(mySetting in myTask))`

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Answer rewritten entirely.